# Is Esther's comment in Esther 7:4 a reference to one of the curses in Devarim 28:68?

Tags: transactions, megillat-esther, slave-serve-eved-avadim, curse, ki-tavo

In [Esther 7:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51099&st=&pgnum=20), Esther says that had the Jews been sold for slaves and maidservants, she would have been silent.

[Devarim 28:68](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=334) says that we would be shipped to Egypt, and we would try to sell ourselves as slaves and maidservants. but no one will buy us.

While I am aware that the verse in Devarim seems to point to selling ourselves in Egypt, I'm not sure that the curse of selling ourselves as slaves was specific to happening in Egypt. It could be anywhere if we didn't follow G-d's commands. History has proven this to be the case as we were slaves in other countries. (Most recently during the Hollocaust.)

I'm curious if what Esther was saying about being silent if we would have been sold as slaves was her way of referring to the verse in Devarim, i.e. that she saw this as a fulfillment of G-d's decree had that actually happened. Are there any commentaries that make this connection?

Comment: Up for grabs, for anyone who can look up the primary sources in the Rokeach, Brisker Rav, and Avnei Shoham: https://books.google.com/books?id=bRD6dI4KLoUC&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=Esther+7:4+Devarim+28:68&source=bl&ots=lpFB79fMIG&sig=IIUEmtge80EGaSwP7wl1J9D3u2k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yDLuVIKgC4v2yQTLyoCAAg&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=Esther%207%3A4%20Devarim%2028%3A68&f=false . And for anyone who can find the reference in the Torah Temimah: http://www.dafyomi.co.il/megilah/backgrnd/mg-in-011.htm , http://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.11a.26-28?lang=he-en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what [@Isaac Moses says](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55746/is-esthers-comment-in-esther-74-a-reference-to-one-of-the-curses-in-devarim-28#comment147047_55746) above, the [Midrash Esther Rabbah, Petihta Guimel](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%97%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%92) also brings:

> ר' יצחק אמר: לעבדים ולשפחות אי אתם נקנין, אבל אתם נקנין להשמיד להרוג
>   ולאבד, שכן אסתר אומרת לאחשורוש: "וְאִלּוּ לַעֲבָדִים וְלִשְׁפָחוֹת
>   נִמְכַּרְנוּ הֶחֱרַשְׁתִּי" שכן כתב לנו משה רבינו בתורה
>   "וְהִתְמַכַּרְתֶּם שָׁם לְאוֹיְבֵיכֶם לַעֲבָדִים וְלִשְׁפָחוֹת וְאֵין
>   קוֹנֶה" שמא "לְהַשְׁמִיד לַהֲרוֹג וּלְאַבֵּד". כיון שראו הכל, התחילו
>   צווחין ווי. ויהי ווי שהיה בימי אחשורוש: